# Bluetooth latency on Chrome?

Tags: bluetooth, google-chrome, headphones, youtube

My bluetooth earbuds have around 200ms delay. On VLC I can correct for this by manually setting an audio sync hasten, but on Chrome (when e.g. watching Youtube) I don't see any way to adjust. Is it possible, or is it literally impossible to watch Youtube on Chrome over Bluetooth synced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had luck with this Chrome plugin, you'll probably need to use a video latency test first:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRSIvFOzRBs&vl=en

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-audiovideo-sync/mknmhikmjljhpccebpnplhicmcfjkgbk

Comment: Thanks! This works for youtube. Any chance you know a plugin that works for other sites? Was hoping to fix it for Chrome once and for all.

Comment: Alas, I don't, I run ubuntu and there's an additional advanced setting for the pulseaudio driver (depending on source) that compensates, independent of chrome, it may be worth reviewing any updates to vendor drivers for your board (often your motherboard vendor will supply firmware updates for sound card drivers if you didn't buy a secondary sound card). Sorry can't be more helpful.